# How to add tab-completion to command with two arguments (and tab complete both)?

Tags: fish, tab-completion

Let's have a command `command`. This command has an option `-o` that takes 2 arguments. I'd like to add tab-completion to both of those arguments.

I've tried

```
complete -c command -x -s o -a "complete first arg"
```

I but cannot add tab-completion to the second argument.

---

I would like to autocomplete the `command` when no option is specified. this work fine:

```
complete -c command -a "no option completion"
```

but when it I hit tab after the first argument in `-o` option, those ^ completions are shown.

like this:

```
command -o "fist" <tab>
no
option
completion
```

if I cannot add completion for the second argument I'd like to at least remove those completions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This command has an option -o that takes 2 arguments.

That's quite unusual. Are you sure about that?

Usually, you'll either have options that take *one* argument, or options that act as "flags" and change all other arguments. So you would just check their presence.

"-o" "-old-style" options also aren't as common as "--gnu-style" long options or "-s" short options, so I suggest double-checking.

> complete -c command -a "no option completion"

This means to offer "no", "option" and "completion" if the command is "command".

There is no condition specified, so these are *always* offered.

What you want is to use the "--condition" (or "-n") option to `complete`. This takes script (as a string) that is executed. If it returns 0 (i.e. true), the corresponding completion (the rest of that `complete` invocation - the option and arguments) is offered.

Something like

```
# The first condition is just to see that `commandline -opc`, 
# which tokenizes (-o) all tokens of the current process (-p) 
# up to (but not including) the cursor (-c)
# returns just one token - which must be the command.
#
# Alternatively this condition could also be 
# the inverse of the other conditions
# (offer this if nothing else would be)
complete -c command -n 'test (count (commandline -opc)) -lt 2' -a 'stuff for no argument'

# The first argument to the option we handle via "-a" to the option
complete -c command -o the-option -a 'the first argument'

# The second argument needs to be offered
# if the second-to-last token is the option.
#
# This is incomplete, because theoretically a token that
# _looks_ like the option could be offered as an argument to _another_ option.
complete -c command -n 'set -l option (commandline -opc)[-2]; test "$option" = "-o"' -a 'the second argument'
```